# EDIT NEW Pass data from the controller to the view using HttpPost

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

- I had to convert the method in the controller from HttpGet to HttpPost.
- The method returns a view to me.
- I have previously sent values ​​to this method via ViewBag.
- Currently, when I use ViewBag, an error is thrown:

  > Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
- The error only pops up when I'm using ViewBag

**controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PartialTabelaEcp(string json)
{ 
    var nr_days= 31;
    ViewBag.days= nr_days;
    return PartialView("_TableEve");
}
```

**.cshtml**

```
//for example
@for (int nr_rows = 0; nr_rows < ViewBag.days; nr_rows++)
{
    var nr_names = nr_rows + 1;
}
```

what I expected?

Help / articles on how to send data from the controller to the view using HttpPost

**EDIT**

for example:
model:

```
 public partial class userDaty_Model
    {
        public int liczbaDniM { get; set; }

        public int numerMiesiacaM { get; set; }

        public int numerRokuM { get; set; }
    }
```

controler:

```
liczbaDni = 1;
numerMiesiaca = 2;
numerRoku= 5;

 userDaty_Model userDaty = new userDaty_Model();
            userDaty.liczbaDniM = liczbaDni;
            userDaty.numerRokuM = numerMiesiaca;
            userDaty.numerMiesiacaM = numerRoku;
 return PartialView("_TableEve", userDaty);
```

and now I have for (razor) and how to throw in it the value assigned in the controller?
**view**

```
   @for (int nr_rows = 0; nr_rows < @aandWhatWriteHere ; nr_rows++)
```

I tried:

```
DayValue : @Html.HiddenFor(item => item.userDaty_Model.liczbaDniM);   // does it works?

@for (int nr_rows = 0; nr_rows <  DayValue; nr_rows++)  // it does not work...
```

Comment: Question 1. Is it MVC or Core? What is it? 2) Where is the code where you were sending it before? You can send it via `Html.Beginform` or a `<form>` or ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It would be easier for you to create a View Model and put the data in it and >return to View with the filled ViewModel Object this could look sth like this
>
> The View Model

```
   public class PartialTableEcpModel
   {
      public List<string> Days {get; set;}
      //And so on

  }
```

> The Controller

```
   public ActionResult PartialTabelaEcp(string json)
   { 
       PartialTableEcpModel tableModel = new PartialTableEcpModel();
       tableModel.Days = new List<string>() {"Day1", "Day2", Day3};
       var nr_days= 31;
       ViewBag.days= nr_days;
       return PartialView("_TableEve", tableModel);
   }
```

> The Razor View

```
   @model PartialTableEcpModel 
   @foreach(var day in Model.Days)
   {
    <p>@day</p>//or whatever
   }
```

> so it is again for a Get request
>
> ### For Edit
>
> you have to set the `@model` thing at the top of the RazorView.cshtml to your model, then the `Model` property in your is the Model you push in the Controller